# How to ensure/check that List is not null before adding item in C#?

Tags: c#, list, null

I have come across this situation many times when we need to add a new item to the list. According to good code practice, we should always check if list is null before adding new item in the list. Below is the sample to make my question clear. Here we have a function AddSubject() which adds a new subject based on some condition. Here we need to check if Subjects field is null. If null then need to create a new list.

For eg:

```
var students = new Student(){Name="Raj Roy", Age= 23, Subjects = new List<string>()};

private void AddSubject(Student stud)
{
    if(stud.Age > 18>
        stud.Subjects.Add("NewSubjectName");
}
```

We have two options for checking if the List field is null:

```
if(stud.Subjects == null)
    stud.Subjects = new List<string>();
```

or

```
stud.Subjects = stud.Subjects ?? new List<string>();
```

I follow the second approach.

I wanted the suggestion of you guys about the best approach out of these two or if there is some other better way.

Comment: Rather than checking for null every time I'd consider initializing the list by default for every student. Also your second option is a bit confusing - was it supposed to be `stud.Subjects ??`, as opposed to `stud.Subject ??`? Either way, if it's only a matter of readability, I think the first one looks better.

Comment: @S_F: Why do you think that second approach is confusing?

Comment: @All: Should not we always initialize the properties of any class whose datatype is List? If no then why so?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put the `Student` object in charge of its own subjects:

```
    class Student
    {
        private readonly string name;

        private readonly int age;

        private readonly IList<string> subjects = new List<string>();

        public Student(string name, int age)
        {
            this.name = name;
            this.age = age;
        }

        public void AddSubject(string subject)
        {
            if (age > 18)
            {
                subjects.Add(subject);
            }
        }

        public IEnumerable<string> Subjects
        {
            get
            {
                return subjects;
            }
        }
    }
```

The [Law of Demeter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter) might cause you to reconsider code such as `stud.Subjects.Add(..)`.

Comment: What if Student class has many (say 12) such properties at Student level as well as Student's child, Student's child's child properties? Do you suggested to have properties like 'AddSubject' for all 12 properties and at each level?

Comment: Probably - though if your classes are getting too big you should consider breaking them down into smaller classes with well-defined responibilities - see 'single responsibility principle'. For example, we might already consider making a 'SubjectList' class which can be unit-tested separately (e.g. we might want to check we cannot add the same subject twice, etc.)

Comment: Continuing with the testing theme, you should make classes that expose behaviours that you can test. If you are breaking the law of demeter and poking around inside your class, it's difficult to know what the real bahaviour of your class in the application is

Answer (score 1):

In fact,

```
stud.Subjects = stud.Subjects ?? new List<string>();
```

is just an syntax sugar of

```
stud.Subjects = stud.Subjects == null ? new List<string>():stud.Subjects;
```

This syntax is originally introduced to aid providing default value for `Nullable<T>` types. So I think this one is better then the previous one with if clause. But I think it makes no differences to the run-time.

**Edit:** (Answer to @Jaroslav Kadlec)

Oh, Precisely speaking, their behavior can be different. If the `stud.Subjects` is an attribute instead of an ordinary field, the additional assignment when `stud.Subjects != null` could also trigger the accessor of `stud.Subjects`, which would make the whole thing different.

That is why using the if one could be a little faster, it has one less assignment.

But I still think it's an VM optimization issus. Since in this case (assume it is a field), this assignment could have been optimized out by the compiler inside VM. But they chose not to do so for some reason.

---

However, As @topo morto had suggested. I think you'd better not expose these implementation details of your `Student` class to the outside world. Even if you do not want to initialize the list by default, you should still initialize it in your `Student` class.

Answer (score 0):

Note that

```
stud.Subjects = stud.Subjects ?? new List<string>();
```

is syntax suger of

```
stud.Subjects = stud.Subjects == null ? new List<string>():stud.Subjects;
```

or

```
if (stud.Subjects == null) {}
else {}
```

at least in 99%.